selenium-webdriver chrome js autoGrantPermission not working
I had enabled chrome options autoGrantPermission to allow browser's location.
However, the popup is still appear on the screen and there is no way to dismiss or accept it..


I'm using selenium-webdriver v4.25.0
and AVD API 35
I also tried with other way such as:

driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss() or driver.switchTo().alert().accept()
find the allow button by id "com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"

both are not working in my case..


how to debug this further? I expected autoGrantPermission is automatically allowing these popups, turns out it is not working?
if it is possible to setup the chrome settings/options through the code (instead of Chrome's setting page), I would really appreciate it!
